# Angular 6 resolver handle route navigation after api call failure

Tags: angular

I would like to fetch place details from server using a route resolver.

When there is no matching place id in database, server respondes with error (
status:-200,
statusText:"PlaceApiController, getPlace(), place does not exist.)
After a custom generic retry logic server interceptor catches the error and throws a 'throwError' Observable.

server.interceptor.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class ServerErrorsInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor(private authService: AuthService, private loaderService: LoaderService) { }

/**
 * intercepts all server calls and retry them x times
 * before throwing an error.
 *
 * @param request
 * @param next
 *
 * @returns {Observable<HttpEvent<any>>}
 */
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request)
        .pipe(
            tap(() => this.loaderService.show()),                
            filter(event => event.type === 4),
            mergeMap(event => this.validateSuccessfulResponseStatus(event)),
            retryWhen(this.genericRetryStrategy()),
            catchError((error) => { 
                return throwError(error)
            }),
            finalize(() => this.loaderService.hide())
        );
  }
}
```

place-resolver.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class PlaceResolverService implements Resolve<PlaceResultDtoModel> {
private getPlaceDtoModel: GetPlacePostDtoModel;

constructor(     
    private placeRepository: PlaceRepository,           
    private router: Router) 
{}

/**
 * @todo
 * 
 * @param route 
 * @param state 
 */
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<PlaceResultDtoModel> | any {
    const placeId = route.paramMap.get("id");

    this.getPlaceDtoModel = {
        id: +placeId
    }                       

    return this.placeRepository.getPlace(this.getPlaceDtoModel).pipe(
        map(placeDetails => {
            if (placeDetails) {
                return placeDetails;
            } else {
                this.router.navigate(["/places"]);
                return null;
            }
        },
        catchError(e => {
            const x = e;                
        }))            
    );
  }
}
```

I would like to navigate back to place list when api get place call returns with an error, but the problem is that 'catchError' inside resolve method is never been called. The console gives the following message:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Object: {"status":-200,"statusText":"PlaceApiController, getPlace(), place does not exist."}
```